# Do equivalent norms preserve dual spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose that $X^*$ is the dual space of a normed space $X$. If we renorm the space $X^*$ with a new norm equivalent to the first one, is this new normed space the dual of $X$ as well?
(I think it suffices to prove that a functional $f$ is continuous with a norm1 if and only if it is continuous with norm2 where norm1 and norm2 are two equivalent norms. This seems to be obvious!).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Since you don't change the vector space $X^*$ by renorming it, it remains the dual as the set of continuous linear functionals on $X$. But it is no longer the dual of $X$ as a normed vector space, since that means precisely $\|f\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} |f(x)|$, which is completely determined by the norm on $X$.

Along these lines, what is true is: if you put an equivalent norm on $X$, then $X$ has the same bounded (= continuous) linear functionals as before, so the vector space $X^*$ remains the same. And both induced norms on $X^*$ are equivalent as well. Maybe that's what you meant to ask.

To prove the statement of that last paragraph, assume first that $\|x\|_1\leq C\|x\|_2$ for some $C>0$. Then $\|x\|_1\leq 1$ whenever $\|Cx\|_2\leq 1$, whence for every linear functional on $X$
$$
C\|f\|_1=C\sup_{\|x\|_1\leq 1}|f(x)|\geq \sup_{\|Cx\|_2\leq 1}|f(Cx)|= \sup_{\|y\|_2\leq 1}|f(y)|=\|f\|_2.
$$
In particular, $f$ is $\|\cdot\|_2$ bounded whenever it is $\|\cdot\|_1$ bounded. The result follows by symmetry.

Comment: Sorry, my last remark wasn't relevant..

Comment: @DavidMitra No problem. I think we both have in mind that the OP meant to renorm $X$, and not $X^*$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what Hamid meant: The equivalence class of the norm on the dual space does *not* determine the predual up to isomorphism. Loosely speaking, the reason is that an automorphism of $X^\ast$ need not be weak\*-continuous (so it need not come from an automorphism of $X$). For example, $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$ are isomorphic, but their natural preduals $\ell_1$ and $L_1$ aren't isomorphic. The space $\ell_1$ famously has a continuum of nonisomorphic preduals (among which the spaces $C(K)$ with $K$ countably infinite and compact).

Comment: @Martin It is not very clear what Hamid meant. I tried two interpretations. Your interpretation is more sophisticated, and more interesting. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1):

For the last statement, suppose $f$ is continuous with respect to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$, and that $k,K > 0$ are so that $k \lVert v \rVert_1 < \lVert v \rVert_2 < K\lVert v \rVert_1$ for all $v \in X$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given, and choose $\delta_0$ so that $\lvert f(v) - f(w) \rvert < \varepsilon$ whenever $\lVert v - w \rVert_1 < \delta_0$. Put $\delta = \delta_0/k$. Then for $\lVert v - w \rVert_2 < \delta$ you have $\lVert v - w \rVert_1 < \delta/k = \delta_0$, so $\lvert f(v)-f(w) \rvert < \varepsilon$, so $f$ is continuous with respect to $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$

Note that this does not use linearity of $f$ and is a general fact about a continuous maps on metric spaces.